# Can sonochemistry be used as a catalyst for basic reactions?

Tags: experimental-chemistry

Recently, I have been interested in the field of sonochemistry, using ultrasonic irradiation to induce chemical changes in a system via the phenomena of acoustic cavitation.

From my rather brief research, I have come to the realization that this phenomena can be used as a catalyst for many reactions. However, I want to know if the most basic form of sonochemistry (using an ultrasonic bath) can be used to speed up very simple inorganic reactions involving dissolved common chemicals.

I am very interested in the implications of this emerging field in chemistry, but am curious as to whether I can perform a few basic experiments using common chemicals and an ultrasonic bath and compare reaction times for a high school science project.

Comment: You migth find the  [Sonocatalysis](http://www.scs.illinois.edu/suslick/documents/sonocatalysis.pdf)  chapter  from the *Handbook of Heterogeneous Catalysis* interesting.